# Quantity of rapid rise yeast vs regular yeast in bread machine

Tags: substitutions, yeast, measurements

How much instant, rapid rise yeast should I use when my bread machine recipe calls for 1 1/2 teaspoons of regular dry yeast?

Answer (score 1):

Google returned [this link](https://anitasorganic.com/tips-techniques/active-vs-instant-yeast/) with the following conversion:

"...1 tsp Active Dry = 2/3 tsp Instant (100% Active Dry = 66% Instant)

1 tsp Instant = 1 1/2 tsp Active Dry (100% Instant = 150% Active Dry)

You can substitute one for the other in any recipe. Remember that active dry must be dissolved in a small amount of lukewarm water before you use it...."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's marked on the side of many yeast containers, too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the rapid rise yeast is just active dry yeast mixed with vitamin C, lecithin (or something similar) and maybe some salts and other trace items and possibly extra gluten. These extra ingredients are known as ["bread improver" or "dough conditioner"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dough_conditioner) and make your yeast grow faster as well as improving gluten structure. Despite Max's assertion, active dry yeast does **not** need to be dissolved before use - I have several recipes for hand made, and all my machine made, that use it undissolved.

Comment: Bread machine, instant and rapid rise yeasts are just ground finer than active yeast. This make the yeast have quicker action. Nothing is added unless it states it on the package. I have never seen anything added to any yeasts.